# How to check if object value is already existing in JSON on android?

Tags: android, arrays, json, string

I have a JSON object which looks like this:

```
{
    "info": [
    {
      "name": "A"
    }, 
    {
       "name": "B"
    },
    {
       "name": "C"
    }]
}
```

I want to know if the name "A" is existing in JSON. I did it like this but it doesn't work.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("info");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   String s = jsonObject.getString(name);
   if(s.equal("C")) {
      //do something
   }
}
```

**Please anyone help. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. Only changes I have done a boolean variable isValueExisting is used to keep track of whether the name "A" exists in the JSON inside the loop. Check below code.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("info");

boolean isValueExisting = false;

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    
    if (name.equals("A")) {
        isValueExisting = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (isValueExisting) {
    // "A" exists, Perform the desired actions here
} else {
    // "A" does not exist in the JSON
}
```

Comment: I did as you say but same problem.

Comment: @Alex Please paste your Json sample here or validate your Json here https://jsoncompare.com/#!/simple/fullscreen/

Comment: I updated Valid JSON, still same problem. please help me, how can I solve it.